# Hooking Event at NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm making popup tooltip in NSWindow, like following XCode tooltip

[image]

If user press a button, popup is shown. It is easy.

But after that, if user press any button in this window, popup should be hidden.

But if user press button, nswindow's mousedown: isn't be called. so nswindowcontroller can not receive that event.

How can nswindow can detect all event in window's region?

Comment: Why not to use contextMenu?

Comment: Do you mean + (void)popUpContextMenu:(NSMenu *)menu withEvent:(NSEvent *)event forView:(NSView *)view function?

Comment: It is menu item but how it can be used as upper popup button?

Comment: upper popup button means?

Comment: At upper attached picture, 'Custom View' popup. I want to make that popup, so I made nsview subclass. Is that 'custom view' popup view nsview? is that somewhat other class?

Comment: that is a custom view drawn that gives you an anglular pointer. If you really need xcode style, then you need to subclass, for small usage contextmenu serves :)

Comment: Can you give any more information or related document url for contextmenu?

Comment: should i post as an answer, as it contains few codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a contextMenu for small window, that opens on your action.

**NOTE:* in the image, that is a custom view, not a contextMenu.*

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    NSRect frame = [(NSButton *)sender frame];
    NSPoint menuOrigin = [[(NSButton *)sender superview] convertPoint:NSMakePoint(frame.origin.x+80, frame.origin.y+frame.size.height-10)
                                                               toView:nil];
    NSEvent *event =  [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseDown
                                         location:menuOrigin
                                    modifierFlags:NSLeftMouseDownMask // 0x100
                                        timestamp:0.0
                                     windowNumber:[[(NSButton *)sender window] windowNumber]
                                          context:[[(NSButton *)sender window] graphicsContext]
                                      eventNumber:0
                                       clickCount:1
                                         pressure:1];
    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    [menu setAutoenablesItems:NO];
    [menu insertItemWithTitle:@"Add Favorite"
                       action:@selector(addFavorite:)
                keyEquivalent:@""
                      atIndex:0];
    [menu insertItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem] atIndex:1];
    [menu insertItemWithTitle:@"Manage Favorite"
                       action:@selector(manageFavorite:)
                keyEquivalent:@""
                      atIndex:2];
      [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:menu withEvent:event forView:(NSButton *)sender];
}

-(IBAction)addFavorite:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"add");
}

-(IBAction)manageFavorite:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"mangage");
}
```